# Memory leak with mongocxx::instance inst{};

Tags: c++, linux, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

Valgrind give me a `still reachable` record with mongocxx::instance inst{};

```
==3014== 16,384 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 609 of 609
==3014==    at 0x5374C20: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:662)
==3014==    by 0x396046ACCE: CRYPTO_realloc (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==3014==    by 0x39604E604D: lh_insert (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==3014==    by 0x39604E87C8: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==3014==    by 0x39604E814B: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==3014==    by 0x396054C2FD: ERR_load_CMS_strings (in /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e)
==3014==    by 0x3963045A38: SSL_load_error_strings (in /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e)
==3014==    by 0x62BD653: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0)
==3014==    by 0x62A2278: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0)
==3014==    by 0x395BC0CE02: pthread_once (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
==3014==    by 0x55ADDE5: std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::impl, std::default_delete<mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::impl> > core::v1::make_unique<mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::impl, void, std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::v_noabi::logger, std::default_delete<mongocxx::v_noabi::logger> > >(std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::v_noabi::logger, std::default_delete<mongocxx::v_noabi::logger> >&&) (in /usr/lib64/libmongocxx.so.3.0.3)
==3014==    by 0x55ADAEE: mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::instance(std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::v_noabi::logger, std::default_delete<mongocxx::v_noabi::logger> >) (in /usr/lib64/libmongocxx.so.3.0.3)
==3014==    by 0x55ADCF4: mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::instance() (in /usr/lib64/libmongocxx.so.3.0.3)
==3014==    by 0x4F6188: main (main.c:280)
```

How do I get rid of this.
I declare the instance after a fork but before creating any thread.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be that you write a suppression for this, after verifying the following:

- Have you verified that the dtor for your `mongocxx::instance` object is executing?
- Have you verified that the dtor of that object is in fact calling `mongoc_cleanup`?

If both of those are true, then your next question is to ask whether libcrypto actually ever frees this allocated data under any path. If the answer to that is yes, then your next question is to ask why it isn't getting called. If the answer to that is "no", then you should write a suppression.

Writing a suppression is likely appropriate here because this is almost certainly a one-time allocation, and thus not tied to a per-operation context which would lead to unbounded memory growth.

Additionally, note that the memory is not actually leaked - it is still reachable.